# How to have an external DB read and get data from my wordpress database

Tags: database, google-chrome

I'm building a Chrome extension and I would like it connected to my wordpress site. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a user register on my wordpress site, and then be able to login using the same credentials on the Chrome extension. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the rest api http://v2.wp-api.org/ you can access data remotely even update posts, etc.

Comment: Note that WordPress cannot be used as an authentication provider on its own. You're going to need a plugin. See this section of the (correct) documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins